# Google Analytics 4 gtm.js not firing

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to track submissions of Hubspot forms embedded in our contact pages with Google Analytics 4 & Google Tag Manager.​

Following [this guide](https://www.knslta.com/articles/track-hubspot-form-submissions-in-ga4), I've created:

•A new GTM HTML tag called "Website Hubspot Form Submission Tracking" with the custom HTML in step 1 above to fire on two Triggers: the Contact Sales Page (URL path contains `contact/sales`) and the Contact Support Page (URL path contains `contact/support`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    if(event.data.type === 'hsFormCallback' && event.data.eventName === 'onFormSubmitted') {
      window.dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'hubspot-form-submit',
        'hs-form-guid': event.data.id
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

• A new GTM trigger called "Hubspot Form Submitted" with event name `hubspot-form-submit` that matches the `window.dataLayer.push({'event': 'hubspot-form-submit',` code added above.

• A new GTM data layer variable called "Hubspot Form GUID" with the variable name `hs-form-guid`.

• A new GTM event tag, selecting the correct GA4 config variable, with event name `website_contact_us_submitted` to be triggered with the "Hubspot Form Submitted" trigger.

I've published these GTM changes.

If I select the "Website Hubspot Form Submission Tracking" tag and debug it, and visit our Contact Sales page, I see

> Website Hubspot Form Submission Tracking Not Fired

If I open the `Tag Not Fired`, I see:

[image]

From [this article](https://www.lynchpin.com/blog/google-tag-manager-tags-not-firing-in-gtm/), I see that *placing the dataLayer declaration after the GTM container will cause the array to be reset*, and the recommended fix for this is to be sure the data being sent to the `dataLayer` is being pushed onto the existing dataLayer using `dataLayer.push`.

However, the code sending data to the dataLayer in the first article I linked to does just that.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {               
      if(event.data.type === 'hsFormCallback' && event.data.eventName === 'onFormSubmitted') {
        window.dataLayer.push({
          'event': 'hubspot-form-submit',
          'hs-form-guid': event.data.id
        });
      }});
  </script>
```

Why is the `gtm.js` event not firing on the Contact Support & Contact Sales pages?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was debugging `Website Hubspot Form Submission Tracking`, which was the wrong tag to debug. When debugging the `Website Hubspot Form Submitted` tag, the GA4 event `website_contact_us_submitted` fired after submitting the Hubspot form.